# How to put if else in @guest laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, database, tailwind-css

So i tried to put an if else in my navbar code that I got from somewhere. but everytime I change @else to @if with a parameter ;

`({{ Auth::user()->tipe }})`

always get error code **syntax error, unexpected token "<"**

```
                    @guest
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 " aria-current="page">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 ">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    @else <!-- I try to put if else here -->
                    
                    <button id="dropdownDefaultButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" class="text-black font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center" type="button">{{ Auth::user()->name }} 
                        <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Dropdown menu -->
                    <div id="dropdown" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
                        <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownDefaultButton">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                Sign out
                                </a>
                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    @endguest
```

Comment: `@guest` ends at `@endguest` and at that point you can just put another block of `@auth... @endauth`. If you really need the if else structure use an actual `@if` statement

Comment: Is there an `Auth::user()` when you're inside `@guest`?

Comment: @brombeer yes i'm trying to get different user a different navbar

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax has to be

```
@guest
  <li>CODE</li>

  @if (Auth::user()->tipe)
    .. CODE IF TRUE ..
  @else
    .. CODE IF FALSE .. 
  @endif

  <li>MORE CODE</li>

@endguest
```

You get your error because you are including `{{ }}` in the condition. `@if({{ Auth::user()->tipe}})` has to be `@if(Auth::user()->tipe)` because it is already interpreted as PHP code.

Comment: This only fixes your error btw, it does nothing regarding @brombeer 's correct comment asking if there is an `Auth::user()` when you are in the `@guest` blade-directive (which there probably isn't).